Change in direction of equilibrium
How does the direction of equilibrium change if an inert gas is added at constant temperature?
I know that it has no effect at constant volume, but what about temperature?
Like does it have no effect or shift toward more no. of mole/less number of moles?

It would be preferable if you include your thought process and working, otherwise your post may attract downvotes and close votes.

In the case of adding inert gas at constant volume and having no effect, that assumes constant temperature and thus constant $\ce{K_p}$. In that scenario, if temperature was able to increase for example, there would be a shift in equilibrium to the more endothermic side as the equilibrium constant itself change. Thus the partial pressures must adjust as well.
So essentially constant temperature is part of the assumption in the scenario you have described with adding inert gas to constant volume.

At constant temperature, the situation becomes simple if either pressure or volume of the system of gases is kept constant as well:
Case 1: At Constant Volume
The partial pressures of the gases in equilibrium remain unchanged, so there is no change as you have mentioned.
Case 2: At Constant Pressure
Since the number of moles of gas increases, to keep pressure of the system constant, volume of the system increases. Hence, partial pressures of the gases in equilibrium decrease and so, the system shifts in that direction of equilibrium where $\Delta n_g>0$ by Le Chatelier's principle. For example, if some moles of Ne are added to an equilibrium mixture containing $\ce N_2$, $\ce H_2$ and $\ce{NH3}$ at constant pressure and temperature:
$$\ce{N2}+\ce{3H2 <=> 2NH3}$$
The equilibrium shifts towards the left side of the above equation, i.e., towards $\ce N_2$ and $\ce H_2$.
